# UDP usage over a quiet line

Tags: network-programming, udp

What are the reasons for UDP dropping packets?

For instance, if I had a line that it was imperative that just one message get through as fast as possible would it make sense to use UDP. That is there is no other traffic on the line, but the packet must reach the other side.

Comment: If it was imperative that the message got through, you should be using TCP.  Packets can drop for any number of reasons, and only using TCP will guarantee receipt on the other end.  If for some reason, the checksum doesn't match on both ends, the packet will simply be dropped with UDP, and won't be resent.  Probably the only way you can really come close to any sort of guarantee of receipt on the receiving end is if the computers are connected directly with say a fiber cable or so, and even then, there's the potential of some fluke causing an issue where the checksum doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons for dropped UDP messages - from bad hardware to software bugs in the equipment.

> That is there is no other traffic on the line, but the packet must
>   reach the other side.

There's no truly easy way to do this. A single UDP message won't work, since it can be dropped for many reasons. TCP won't work either, since it has timeouts and retransmits etc. If you are unlucky and the first few segments are lost it can take many seconds until your message makes it through.

There is an easy and somewhat hacky thing you can do:

- The sender starts sending as fast as feasible - you define this - the same message over and over again using UDP
- The receiver replies to every message with an ACK "Alright already, enough with the spam"
- When the sender gets the ACK, it stops

Comment: This should work...interesting angle on it too, I hadn't thought of that.